# Making Character move around circle

Tags: java, box2d, game-physics, trigonometry

So I have a 2d game which normally just has gravity and "flat" levels however I have added in "planets" which have their own gravity.

I have a function called addForce(float xForce, float yForce) that I use to move my character. So say if I called player.addForce(1, -1); the player would move up and to the right(albeit slightly). This worked fine on the levels with regular downward gravity, however with planets it is not so. 
There is another float called earthAngle which is:

> atan2(player.getY()-earth.getY(), player.getX()-earth.getX());

What I did for the jumping code on the planets is:

> player.addForce(cos(earthAngle)*1500, sin(earthAngle)*1500);

which works well. However I am stuck on how to make the character walk around the planet.

Currently for the movement code I have:

> player.addForce(25*x_*cos(earthAngle), 25+x_*sin(earthAngle));

which only works on some parts and works in reverse on the bottom as well as being stronger/weaker on some parts, x_ can be either -1(left) or 1(right). I'm guessing their is a really elegant solution I am just overlooking. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing elegant about the question, please reformat it a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have the vector from the center of the planet to the player eg (x,y), you can use a vector perpendicular to that (-y,x) as the direction for the walking force.

Comment: edit: nevermind, I understand. Thanks a alot, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Very nice solution, but won't it only work for finding points on the circle if the planet's center is at (0,0)?

Comment: @LFA2711
Nope. The 'vector from planet center to player position' is just a direction, not a location. For example if the player is standing directly on top of a planet of radius 1, this vector would be (0,1). It doesn't matter where the planet and player pair are in the world, the relationship between them is the same.